# Is it safe for my laptop to power a USB powered monitor?

Tags: usb, laptop, multiple-monitors, power

I have a laptop Helios 300 2019 model and bought AOC E1670SW 15.6" LED Monitor that is USB powered monitor.

Now while looking for reviews, I stumble to a review that a usb powered monitor burnt up his motherboard.

So I'm really concerned using my laptop to power up my monitor it might end the same case.

My monitor has Power Rating of 5V===3A. And my laptop have USB 3.0 ports.

Is it safe to use my laptop to power the monitor or not?

Comment: whoever downvoted my question, please let me know why. so I can do better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not come across it before, and my natural instinct is to be wary of this - it's certainly pushing things a bit. While likely possible in practice, it's not a great idea.

Based on your statement - The spec for USB 3.0 is 900 mA, so even 3 of these will be less then the rated requirement, so you are running out of spec.

On the other hand, https://www.amazon.in/gp/aw/d/B00JFTY5SU#Ask says that in practice the monitor draws 7 watts, which is less then half the claimed wattage, and it works with a Y-cable even on USB 2. Similarly my 2016 Dell laptop has a USB 2 port which supports 2 amps, so it is entirely possible your laptop will drive this OK.

I do observe that properly designed USB equipment has resettable fuses or similar to protect from overcurrent, so in theory it should not kill your laptop. In practice, some devices leave out this protection and motherboard damage can result. (I blew a USB port on an HP laptop because of this. Luckily I didnt fry my motherboard though...)

Likewise, according to https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-predator-helios-300/specs/ the USB ports for that laptop are different to what you represented. This may or may not be relevant to its ability to meet your requirements.